# Row Model "Server Side" not found. Please ensure the ag-Grid Enterprise Module @ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model is registered.';

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm recently getting this error unable to load all the ag-grid tables. I googled it and added like this
import { LicenseManager } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/core";
import { ModuleRegistry, AllModules } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";
import { ServerSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model";

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([AllModules, ServerSideRowModelModule]);**strong text**

Comment: Did you add it to dependencies (package.json) and install?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether your project is using AG Grid packages or modules there are different fixes required to use the Server Side Row Model.

To check if you are using packages or modules see which you have in your `package.json` file.

| Modules | Packages |
| --- | --- |
| @ag-grid-community/xxxxx | ag-grid-community |
| @ag-grid-enterprise/xxxxx | ag-grid-enterprise |

**Packages Fix**

Make sure you have both community and enterprise packages installed.

```json
"ag-grid-community": "^27.2.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^27.2.0",
```

Then make sure you have imported the enterprise features with this import.

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

That should be all you need to do to enable all the enterprise features including the Server Side Row Model.

**Modules**

Make sure you have installed the Server Side Row model module.

```json
"@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "^27.2.0",
```

Then make sure you have registered the module along with any other modules that you are using.

```
import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { ServerSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model";

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
    ServerSideRowModelModule,
]);
```

That should be all you need to do to enable all the enterprise features including the Server Side Row Model.

I have written about this more in this [blog post](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/).